# Cannot use Boost Library in Xcode IDE project/workspace?

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, path, ide

It seems I have done everything humanly possible to incorporate Boost successfully into my Xcode C++ workspace, which I derived from the project.

Here is what I have done:

TERMINAL "sudo port install boost" -> boost header is now located in /opt/local/include/ and dylibs are located in /opt/local/lib.

Then I "#include "boost/multi_array.hpp" into one of my files, went to my target settings, set the "search header paths" settings to /opt/local/include. That did not work. Xcode redlighted the #include with "file not found." I then looked at a couple youtube videos, which did not help at all. I figured I might try to "link binary with libraries" option and copied the libboost math dylibs into the workspace. That still did not work.

I know this missing file issue is due to an incorrect path, I tried changing the location setting through the options "Relative to group or workspace or developer directory", but the effort was to no avail. I also reinstalled Xcode, and the problem still persists.

Any tips or suggestions would be GREATLY, and I use this word with the truest sincerity, appreciated. :)

Comment: Strange. I just created a xcode project and included boost/multi_array.hpp and typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type in main and it compiles fine. Are you shure you spelled /opt/local/include correct? Sometimes I've written inlcude when I haven't used autocomplete.

Comment: yes, the spelling is correct. In all seriousness, this little issue has been vexing me for the past day and a half, seeing as how I've exhausted my search engine of queries.

Comment: Yeah, annoying when such things happen. Did you create a new class with separate header and cpp files and include multi_array in that header file?

Comment: yes, I did. I tried the #include "boost/multi_array.hpp" in both the cpp and hpp.

Comment: Found the error. Gave an answer below. You only need to include the header-file in your own header file. It was late night so I didn't spot it then. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the double-quotes in your include line to a greater- and less-sign.

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>
```

Comment: wow. Thanks man. Always the simplest solutions to the most frustrating solutions, huh?

Comment: Glad it helped. You can mark the answer as correct if you wish.